# Sobre Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Boa noite! 
Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade que é uma loja online. Pois bem, eu não estava conseguindo fazer com que o botão comprar enviasse para a página "carrinho de compras" até que um amigo me falou sobre Local Storage, o problema é que nunca vi nada sobre, será que alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?
To fazendo em html, já tenho o botão compra, preciso fazer que isso mande as informações do produto (preço, nome) para o carrinho de compras e depois que chegar lá ele some os preços, caso tenha mais de um produto.
Obs: Sou iniciante.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O Local Storage é um recurso para persistência de dados locais que está disponível desde o HTML5. Isso significa que os browser mais recentes devem ter suporte.

Quando eu digo persistência de dados locais, estou querendo dizer que você salvará os dados no navegador da pessoa, sem necessidade de persistir em uma base de dados que está no seu servidor.

O Local Storage salva por padrão strings, mas nada te impede de serializar JSONs e armazenar como se fosse strings.

Como se trata de um projeto de faculdade, eu não sei o quão exigente o seu professor vai ser. Se fosse em um cenário real, eu acredito que Local Storage não seria a tecnologia ideal para implementar um carrinho de compras.

Você pode entender mais sobre o Local Storage aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage